# PHP getting IP address isn't working

Tags: php

I am  trying to add the user's ip address into the database but it doesn't work
I ran `getIP($session_user_id);`
with this function:

```
 function getIP($user_id){
        foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
            if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
                foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $_SERVER[$key])) as $ip){
                    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `ip_address` = '$ip' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

why is it not working? could it be because I am using localhost? any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you describe _not working_ ?

Comment: nothing showed up on the website when I echo it and nothing new in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client is using a proxy or Tor or anything like that, you won't be able to discover the IP address.

Also there are some ISPs where you will not be able to discover the IP address for any of their customers, as we run out of IP addresses this is becoming more and more common.

At the end of the day, it's simply not good enough to rely on IP addresses for anything these days. It's useful for logging when available, but you can't depend on it.

Also, as you said, if you're using localhost it might not work. Beware all of this stuff depends on the server. So your development environment will give different data to the production environment.

REMOTE_ADDR should always exist on most servers, but it will often be wrong when it does exist. The other values may or may not exist and are of unknowable accuracy. Sometimes they're accurate, sometimes not. You're going to have to store more than just one IP address in your logs.

Comment: +1, the network address is for network routing.  Nothing more.

Comment: So what would you recommend storing? I want to be able to ban a user from the website and get their location (country and region is good enough)

Comment: You can't determine a location from an IP address, for example in my case all IP address lookup services pick up my location as 2,000km/1,200mi from where I actually live. This applies to everyone who lives in my city, and many other cities around the world.

Comment: And you can't identify a user from their IP address. There might be ten million people sharing a single IP address, or a single person might have an IP address that changes every 30 minutes. Or something in between. You might block millions of users by banning a single IP, and the one who is malicious will probably change their IP address to something else immediately.

Comment: It simply isn't possible to use IP addresses for this. I realise many websites try to do so, but it doesn't work properly. The best way to ban someone is to ask for their email address or even better their credit card number. That you can be pretty sure is unique to one user.

Comment: As for what you should store, you should store all the values that exist, which will change from one user to another. That's what we use when we need logging. Also don't assume it's an IPv4 address — make sure your database column can store IPv6 addresses (for example: `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the IP address may be different for your localhost. When I try to get the IP address for my localhost, it does not even resemble an IP address.

However, the following code will help you retrieve the IP address when you are not on your localhost.

```
function getIp() {
    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')
        ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')
        ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')
        ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')
        ?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');   
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: What happens if three of those values have different IP addresses? You need to store all three, not just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
   public function getRealIPAddress() {
        $ip= "";
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  //check ip from share internet
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

Works most of the time. but see nothing can be taken for granted these days. what abhi said is true too.

Answer (score 0):

I picked this up years ago from somewhere - not sure

It works about 80% of time

The logic goes

```
 if $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] is NOT null 

 then use the value in $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']  

 otherwise set the vaule to $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

 $ipa = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: The other 20% of the time, Internet is down. :-)